# Dynamic DNS, basic configuration not working

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, dhcp, internal-dns

I'm trying to implement DDns, where DHCP daemon updates dns records instead of myself. From what I understand, it should work. But it doesn't. I would be very grateful, if somebody points out my missconfiguration.

File permissions are correct, keys located at both servers are identical. Centos 7 is used. Everything is working inside NATed KVM.

DNS: 192.168.1.10

DHCP: 192.168.1.100

SUBNET: 192.168.1.0/24

and my configs:

**named.conf:**

```
 acl good_guys {
        192.168.1.0/24;
};


include "/etc/rndc.key";
controls {
         inet 127.0.0.1 allow {192.168.1.10; localhost;} keys {"rndc-key";}; 
};



options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.10; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { localhost; good_guys; };
        allow-query-cache { localhost; any; };

        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "matrix.lab" IN {
        type master;
        file "matrix.lab.zone";
        allow-update { key "rndc-key"; };
        notify yes;
};


include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

**zone file**

```
; Authoritative data for matrix.lab zone
;

$TTL 1D

@ IN SOA mistrz.matrix.lab.     root.mistrz.matrix.lab. (
                                                2018120202 ; serial
                                                1D      ;refresh
                                                1H      ;retry
                                                1W      ;expire
                                                3H )    ;minimum

                IN      NS      mistrz.matrix.lab.
mistrz          IN      A       192.168.1.10
```

**dhcpd.conf**

```
include "/etc/rndc.key";

ddns-updates on;
ddns-update-style interim;
ddns-domainname                 "matrix.lab.";

option domain-name-servers      192.168.1.10;
option domain-name              "matrix.lab";
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range                           192.168.1.200 192.168.1.240;
        option routers                  192.168.1.1;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.255.0;
        default-lease-time              600;
        max-lease-time                  7200;
        ddns-domainname "matrix.lab";


}

zone matrix.lab. {          
        primary 192.168.1.10; 
        key rndc-key;
}
```

**rndc.key**

```
    key "rndc-key" {
        algorithm hmac-sha256;
        secret "8OpW4HhkzT6yvkMMhB9kcsE0xfB/NHkaOtbDRSdIARI=";
};
```

and output of **rndc status**:

```
version: 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-61.el7_5.1 <id:8f9657aa>
CPUs found: 1
worker threads: 1
UDP listeners per interface: 1
number of zones: 7
debug level: 0
xfers running: 0
xfers deferred: 0
soa queries in progress: 0
query logging is OFF
recursive clients: 0/0/1000
tcp clients: 0/100
server is up and running
root@mistrz:~#
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what you want to do in the first place and how that fails.

Comment: Ok, edited. I think it's understandable now.